# How to implement Rabin Karp algorithm for multiple pattern search?

Tags: php, rabin-karp

I have no idea using Rabin Karp alhorithm for multiple pattern search. I've tried to look for it on the internet. I've found that I want, but unfortunatelly in golang. How to use this code in PHP or can I use it in PHP?

```
txt := "a man a plan a canal panama"
patterns := []string{"man", "boat", "plan", "ana", "banana"}
matches := rabinkarp.Search(txt, patterns)

fmt.Println(matches)
```

**Output**

```
// Output:
// [man plan ana]
```

[Full Code](https://github.com/glkz/rabinkarp)

Comment: Have you tried googling before asking? I'm just wondering, because I managed to find the relevant result quickly.

Comment: @N.B. yes, I have. I just found the single pattern. wow..great.. could you give me the link for the multiple pattern using php?

Comment: So post the code you found (in php), let's see what's not working for your use case and take it from there? Some `go` code won't help anyone find the same solution using php.

Comment: @N.B. [link] http://pastebin.com/ingdc71B   this code give error message like this **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$patterns' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\rk\cek.php on line 45**

Comment: @N.B. I think this one http://pastebin.com/n2X6Wz0u is for multiple pattern, but this code shows the error message **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\rk\kr.php:136 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\rk\kr.php(183): stringMatching('algoritma metod...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\rk\kr.php on line 136**